# str_replace (search) large number of strings from a certain JSON value?

Tags: php, arrays, json, preg-replace, str-replace

What is the best and fastest approach to do a string search and replace from a certain JSON value if it has lets say more than 100 strings to search in and each string needs its own unique replacement?

Is it better to create a php subclass with preg_replace using arrays and then import this into another PHP file where the JSON gets parsed?

My PHP knowledge is not that great and would appriciate if someone can guide me through this with some examples.

Here is my JSON code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$licensePlate = $_GET['kenteken'];
$json = file_get_contents('https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?$q='.$licensePlate.'');

$array = json_decode($json);

if(count($array,1)==0) {

    $data = ['resource' => ['code' => '404']];
    echo json_encode($data);

    return;
}

$item = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $item['code'] = '200';
    $item['Aantalcilinders']=$value->aantal_cilinders;
    $item['Aantalzitplaatsen']=$value->aantal_zitplaatsen;
    $item['BPM']=$value->bruto_bpm;
    $item['Cilinderinhoud']=$value->cilinderinhoud;
    $item['Datumaanvangtenaamstelling']=$value->datum_tenaamstelling;
    $item['DatumeersteafgifteNederland']=$value->datum_eerste_afgifte_nederland;
    $item['Datumeerstetoelating']=$value->datum_eerste_toelating;
    $item['Eerstekleur']=$value->eerste_kleur;
    $item['Handelsbenaming']=$value->handelsbenaming; <--this value needs to be replaced in some cases
    $item['Inrichting']=$value->inrichting;
    $item['Kenteken']=$value->kenteken;
    $item['Merk']=$value->merk;
}

$data = ['resource' => ($item)];

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Thanks!

Ps. Excuse my language, I'm from the Netherlands.

Comment: An example JSON string would be helpful. Current thinking though is decode the JSON and mutate the resulting arrays / objects and then re-encode. Safer imo.

Comment: Sorry, post is updated.

Comment: Inside your loop you'll need to use something like `$item[] = array('code'=>'200', 'Aantalcilinders'=>$value->aantal_cilinders, [..]);`. Otherwise you'll end up using only the last row of the json array.

Comment: Thats ok as it has only one object